# How to login with to a remote linux host with RDP passwordless, using my private key?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, authentication, xrdp

**tl:dr**

- I can successfully log in with SSH passwordless using my private key.
- I can successfully log in with RDP using a username and a password.

I would like to log in passwordless with RDP, authenticating myself with my private key.

**details:**

I have an Ubuntu 22.04. I've successfully configured SSH service and also successfully configured a user who can log in using SSH private key authentication
I also successfully installed xfce and xrdp (also xorgxrdp) and now I can log in with RDP with username/password and get the xfce desktop remotely.

Now I would like to log in passwordless with RDP, authenticating myself with my private key.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to save your RDP password to the Windows Credentials Manager? ([example link](https://woshub.com/fix-saved-rdp-credentials-windows/))

Comment: It is not about that. I do not want to have the user password at all, for security reasons. Just the same logic as it would be in case of SSH